# SVG not rendering only in in Safari (v10)

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

I have an SVG file (source below) which I tried to use in 2 ways on my website:

**(1) As an image**

```
<img src="/images/icons/play-button.svg">
```

**(1) As abackground image**

```
<div class="play-button"></div>
```

and CSS:

```
.play-button {
    background: url('/images/icons/play-button.svg') no-repeat 0 0;
    background-size: 196px 96px;
    width: 196px;
    height: 96px;
}
```

In any of the cases above, the SVG is **not** rendered in Safari 10 (both on a Mac and an iPad). Other browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE) render the image correctly.

Also, I tried using other SVGs which worked just fine. The difference between the failng SVG and the other ones is the the former has text transformed to paths, but I'm not sure whether that's a real problem.

What might be the reason of Safari failing to render the image?

The SVG source:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="196" height="96" viewBox="0 0 196 96">
<g fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd" style="mix-blend-mode:darken">
    <path fill-rule="nonzero" d="M94.89 62.883s-.146 7.214-2.024 10.59c-2.349 4.388-6.074 6.2-7.706 6.854-.547.183-1.107.387-1.671.574l-.005-.017c-.74.271-1.58.243-2.306-.177-1.326-.765-1.782-2.468-1.012-3.777a2.7 2.7 0 0 1 1.504-1.198l-.009-.034c.084-.022.181-.066.265-.089 1.355-.543 4.402-1.378 6.34-5.005 1.549-2.783.894-7.993.894-7.993s-.873-6.09-2.45-11.975l-2.205-8.228c-1.58-5.902-3.866-11.596-3.866-11.596s-2.037-4.84-4.77-6.475c-3.492-2.172-6.549-1.372-7.993-1.165-10.19 1.899-27.236 6.466-27.236 6.466s-17.047 4.568-26.846 7.989c-1.355.543-4.402 1.378-6.34 5.006-1.549 2.782-.91 7.996-.91 7.996s.872 6.091 2.45 11.976l2.204 8.228c1.581 5.901 3.866 11.596 3.866 11.596s2.038 4.84 4.77 6.474c3.492 2.173 7.044 1.131 8.727 1.005 5.882-.98 26.536-6.315 26.536-6.315a2.801 2.801 0 0 1 3.42 1.975 2.801 2.801 0 0 1-1.974 3.42.384.384 0 0 1-.14.02c-1.707.44-21.325 5.461-28.11 6.575-2.022.144-6.754.761-10.986-1.882-3.315-1.985-7.03-8.164-7.03-8.164S7.87 80.001 5.956 72.852l-2.517-9.391C1.53 56.328.834 50.298.834 50.298s.16-7.163 2.037-10.54c2.332-4.383 6.065-6.233 7.697-6.887 11.833-4.128 28.61-8.624 28.61-8.624l.033-.009s16.777-4.495 29.089-6.836c1.74-.25 5.88-.51 10.108 2.116 3.315 1.985 7.039 8.126 7.039 8.126s2.41 5.553 4.325 12.702l2.516 9.391C94.2 56.87 94.89 62.883 94.89 62.883zM65.887 80.702a2.801 2.801 0 0 1 3.42 1.975 2.801 2.801 0 0 1-1.974 3.42 2.801 2.801 0 0 1-3.42-1.974 2.801 2.801 0 0 1 1.974-3.421zM50.132 70.123l-.012.021a2.78 2.78 0 0 1-1.262.754 2.764 2.764 0 0 1-3.378-1.95 2.734 2.734 0 0 1 .806-2.728L58.079 55.2s-.038-.009-.022-.013a1.38 1.38 0 0 0 .434-1.417 1.372 1.372 0 0 0-.965-.97l-18.41-4.302a1.255 1.255 0 0 0-.627.023 1.38 1.38 0 0 0-.993 1.622l4.472 16.692-.033.009.009.034a2.801 2.801 0 0 1-1.975 3.42 2.801 2.801 0 0 1-3.42-1.975L31.514 49.54a5.692 5.692 0 0 1 4.024-6.97 5.616 5.616 0 0 1 3.045.034c.038.008.055.004.072 0l21.488 5.735c.451.132.894.302 1.322.55a5.594 5.594 0 0 1 2.046 7.637 5.86 5.86 0 0 1-.799 1.064L50.237 70.04a.851.851 0 0 0-.105.083z"/>
    <path d="M96.976 18.137a1.945 1.945 0 0 0-.856-.367 2.159 2.159 0 0 0-.867.059 1.888 1.888 0 0 0-.737.371c-.202.17-.357.387-.463.65a2.443 2.443 0 0 0-.155.936c.003.361.065.77.188 1.23.125.463.267.846.428 1.148.161.302.338.536.532.702.194.166.403.267.628.304.225.036.461.021.709-.045.396-.106.712-.28.946-.519.234-.24.434-.544.6-.914l-.953-3.555zm.414-6.09l3.077 11.483-1.167.312c-.253.068-.444-.005-.573-.22l-.367-.72c-.221.45-.509.845-.863 1.183-.354.338-.806.58-1.358.728a2.716 2.716 0 0 1-1.262.049 2.745 2.745 0 0 1-1.141-.535c-.352-.273-.667-.643-.944-1.11-.277-.467-.502-1.025-.676-1.674a5.595 5.595 0 0 1-.2-1.702 4.127 4.127 0 0 1 .336-1.498c.2-.451.48-.837.841-1.157a3.21 3.21 0 0 1 1.323-.69c.443-.119.84-.15 1.192-.096.351.055.682.168.993.339l-1.12-4.18 1.909-.512zm8.243 6.47c-.544.174-.995.346-1.352.516-.358.17-.635.34-.833.51-.198.168-.326.338-.385.508a.851.851 0 0 0-.02.51c.089.336.252.549.49.64.236.09.514.094.834.008.391-.105.711-.266.959-.485.248-.218.47-.508.666-.87l-.359-1.336zm-5.295-2.266c.688-1.08 1.674-1.79 2.957-2.134a3.33 3.33 0 0 1 1.305-.106c.406.054.772.183 1.097.386.325.202.603.474.835.815.233.341.409.736.529 1.184l1.342 5.007-.866.232c-.18.048-.327.059-.439.03-.112-.027-.219-.116-.32-.266l-.323-.526a7.143 7.143 0 0 1-.46.633 3.58 3.58 0 0 1-.503.503 3.31 3.31 0 0 1-.604.39 3.94 3.94 0 0 1-.756.281c-.335.09-.657.128-.964.113a2.11 2.11 0 0 1-.843-.209 1.886 1.886 0 0 1-.66-.544 2.469 2.469 0 0 1-.42-.889c-.053-.2-.073-.41-.06-.626.014-.216.073-.435.177-.656a2.83 2.83 0 0 1 .454-.668c.2-.225.46-.444.78-.657.322-.213.707-.42 1.156-.62.448-.2.972-.389 1.57-.566l-.123-.463c-.143-.53-.361-.893-.656-1.088-.295-.194-.657-.234-1.084-.12-.31.084-.556.188-.74.315a3.276 3.276 0 0 0-.472.387c-.13.132-.249.25-.356.357a.863.863 0 0 1-.392.22.57.57 0 0 1-.368-.012.902.902 0 0 1-.29-.184l-.503-.52zm12.984-3.007a.527.527 0 0 1-.115.217.435.435 0 0 1-.203.108.706.706 0 0 1-.318.003c-.12-.023-.258-.049-.414-.076a3.48 3.48 0 0 0-.522-.046 2.356 2.356 0 0 0-.65.091c-.376.101-.65.26-.821.477a.772.772 0 0 0-.153.712c.046.17.14.298.281.384.142.086.316.149.522.187.207.039.435.062.686.07.25.007.506.02.768.038.261.018.522.049.782.092.26.044.504.122.73.235.226.114.425.269.597.466.171.197.3.455.385.774.103.382.129.752.078 1.11a2.36 2.36 0 0 1-.383.997 2.962 2.962 0 0 1-.846.815 4.463 4.463 0 0 1-1.31.562 4.47 4.47 0 0 1-.82.141c-.273.021-.542.02-.805-.004a4.294 4.294 0 0 1-.747-.13 3.34 3.34 0 0 1-.64-.243l.245-.844a.645.645 0 0 1 .147-.255.583.583 0 0 1 .275-.148.639.639 0 0 1 .363.01c.124.039.266.078.425.118.16.04.343.068.55.085.205.016.452-.014.74-.091.227-.061.415-.14.562-.238.148-.097.263-.204.345-.32a.826.826 0 0 0 .15-.367.947.947 0 0 0-.022-.38.664.664 0 0 0-.289-.41 1.505 1.505 0 0 0-.523-.192 4.404 4.404 0 0 0-.69-.068 21.41 21.41 0 0 1-.779-.035 6.883 6.883 0 0 1-.796-.097 2.536 2.536 0 0 1-.739-.254 1.973 1.973 0 0 1-.608-.508c-.177-.217-.313-.501-.406-.851a2.364 2.364 0 0 1-.056-.98c.05-.328.171-.635.362-.92a2.92 2.92 0 0 1 .794-.777 4.032 4.032 0 0 1 1.242-.543 4.102 4.102 0 0 1 1.564-.13c.496.06.933.198 1.31.411l-.248.804zm10.548-2.827a.527.527 0 0 1-.115.218.435.435 0 0 1-.203.108.706.706 0 0 1-.319.002c-.119-.023-.257-.048-.413-.075a3.48 3.48 0 0 0-.522-.047 2.356 2.356 0 0 0-.65.092c-.377.1-.65.26-.821.477a.772.772 0 0 0-.153.711c.046.17.14.299.281.385.142.086.316.148.522.187.207.039.435.062.685.069.25.007.507.02.769.038.261.019.522.05.782.093.26.044.504.122.73.235.226.113.425.269.597.466.171.197.3.455.385.774.103.381.128.751.078 1.11a2.36 2.36 0 0 1-.383.997 2.962 2.962 0 0 1-.846.815 4.463 4.463 0 0 1-1.31.562 4.47 4.47 0 0 1-.82.141c-.274.02-.542.02-.805-.004a4.294 4.294 0 0 1-.747-.13 3.34 3.34 0 0 1-.64-.243l.245-.845a.645.645 0 0 1 .147-.255.583.583 0 0 1 .275-.148.639.639 0 0 1 .363.01c.124.04.266.079.425.119.16.04.343.068.549.085.206.016.453-.014.742-.092.226-.06.414-.14.561-.237.148-.098.263-.204.345-.32a.826.826 0 0 0 .15-.368.947.947 0 0 0-.023-.379.664.664 0 0 0-.288-.41 1.505 1.505 0 0 0-.523-.192 4.404 4.404 0 0 0-.69-.068 21.41 21.41 0 0 1-.779-.035 6.883 6.883 0 0 1-.796-.098 2.536 2.536 0 0 1-.739-.253 1.973 1.973 0 0 1-.608-.508c-.177-.218-.313-.501-.406-.852a2.364 2.364 0 0 1-.056-.979c.05-.328.171-.635.362-.92a2.92 2.92 0 0 1 .794-.777 4.032 4.032 0 0 1 1.242-.544 4.102 4.102 0 0 1 1.564-.129c.496.06.933.197 1.31.41l-.248.804zm6.947 1.353c-.544.173-.995.345-1.353.515-.357.17-.635.34-.832.51-.198.168-.326.338-.386.508a.851.851 0 0 0-.02.51c.09.336.253.549.49.64.237.091.515.094.834.008.392-.105.712-.266.96-.485.248-.218.47-.508.665-.87l-.358-1.336zm-5.295-2.267c.688-1.079 1.674-1.79 2.956-2.134a3.33 3.33 0 0 1 1.305-.105c.407.054.773.182 1.098.385.324.203.603.474.835.815.232.341.408.736.528 1.184l1.342 5.007-.865.232c-.18.048-.327.059-.44.03-.112-.027-.218-.116-.32-.266l-.322-.526a7.143 7.143 0 0 1-.46.633 3.58 3.58 0 0 1-.503.503 3.31 3.31 0 0 1-.604.39 3.94 3.94 0 0 1-.757.281c-.335.09-.656.128-.963.113a2.11 2.11 0 0 1-.843-.209 1.886 1.886 0 0 1-.66-.544 2.469 2.469 0 0 1-.42-.889c-.054-.2-.074-.41-.06-.626.014-.216.073-.435.176-.656a2.83 2.83 0 0 1 .455-.668c.2-.225.46-.444.78-.657.322-.213.707-.42 1.155-.62.45-.2.973-.389 1.571-.565l-.124-.464c-.142-.53-.36-.893-.656-1.087-.295-.195-.656-.235-1.083-.12-.31.083-.556.188-.74.314a3.276 3.276 0 0 0-.472.388l-.356.356a.863.863 0 0 1-.392.22.57.57 0 0 1-.368-.012.902.902 0 0 1-.29-.184l-.503-.52zm11.64-.262c.238-.063.435-.15.593-.262.158-.112.28-.24.365-.384.086-.144.137-.304.153-.48.017-.175 0-.358-.052-.549-.105-.392-.305-.67-.6-.837-.297-.166-.679-.187-1.148-.061-.469.125-.79.334-.962.626-.173.292-.207.634-.102 1.026.05.185.125.35.227.494.102.143.227.258.374.343.147.084.318.135.513.152.195.017.408-.006.64-.068zm3.366 3.935a.547.547 0 0 0-.24-.341.946.946 0 0 0-.44-.127 2.9 2.9 0 0 0-.593.03c-.22.032-.452.074-.695.125-.243.051-.494.106-.751.164a8.948 8.948 0 0 1-.763.138 1.85 1.85 0 0 0-.402.555.88.88 0 0 0-.048.609c.038.14.107.26.21.362.101.103.24.177.415.224.176.047.391.063.646.047.256-.016.558-.071.909-.165.355-.095.654-.205.897-.328a2.29 2.29 0 0 0 .578-.395.998.998 0 0 0 .276-.438.86.86 0 0 0 0-.46zm-.246-8.523l.19.711c.06.227-.038.403-.298.527l-.675.322c.181.244.315.529.402.853.105.392.121.767.05 1.126a2.446 2.446 0 0 1-.437.982 3.168 3.168 0 0 1-.848.778 4.141 4.141 0 0 1-1.176.51 4.355 4.355 0 0 1-.455.097c-.148.023-.295.04-.441.052-.207.216-.286.416-.236.602.042.16.147.257.314.292.167.036.375.036.626.002.25-.034.531-.088.842-.163.311-.075.633-.144.964-.205.332-.061.66-.1.987-.12.326-.018.63.01.909.084.279.075.524.212.735.412.211.2.367.488.468.865.094.35.098.713.014 1.089a2.837 2.837 0 0 1-.513 1.082c-.258.345-.605.66-1.04.945-.434.285-.955.508-1.563.671-.597.16-1.133.242-1.607.245-.474.002-.884-.053-1.23-.168a2.07 2.07 0 0 1-.835-.492 1.622 1.622 0 0 1-.428-.73c-.1-.371-.07-.712.087-1.022.157-.31.411-.592.763-.846a1.378 1.378 0 0 1-.618-.298c-.172-.147-.298-.368-.376-.661a1.157 1.157 0 0 1-.033-.385c.01-.138.04-.28.093-.427a1.91 1.91 0 0 1 .226-.437c.1-.145.225-.285.376-.42a2.59 2.59 0 0 1-1.178-.612c-.326-.299-.554-.69-.684-1.175a2.442 2.442 0 0 1-.049-1.125c.073-.36.22-.689.44-.988.22-.3.507-.56.859-.78a4.389 4.389 0 0 1 1.208-.515c.34-.091.669-.142.986-.152.318-.011.618.018.901.085l2.28-.61zm7.058 1.09a2.378 2.378 0 0 0-.291-.67 1.72 1.72 0 0 0-.468-.492 1.507 1.507 0 0 0-.633-.249 1.88 1.88 0 0 0-.784.057c-.552.148-.944.421-1.176.82-.233.4-.316.9-.249 1.5l3.601-.965zm-3.33 2.127c.14.399.306.731.498.997.193.266.408.47.645.614.237.144.496.229.777.256.28.027.575-.001.884-.084.31-.083.566-.19.771-.322.205-.133.38-.265.523-.397.144-.133.27-.252.376-.358a.765.765 0 0 1 .338-.206c.16-.043.295-.016.404.082l.735.549a3.293 3.293 0 0 1-.545.812 4.128 4.128 0 0 1-.715.622 4.657 4.657 0 0 1-.816.447c-.285.12-.567.218-.845.293a4.385 4.385 0 0 1-1.612.137 3.564 3.564 0 0 1-1.453-.48 3.941 3.941 0 0 1-1.183-1.107c-.343-.475-.607-1.06-.793-1.755a4.544 4.544 0 0 1-.147-1.596 3.8 3.8 0 0 1 .42-1.446c.233-.441.557-.827.974-1.16.416-.332.92-.578 1.512-.736.5-.134.983-.178 1.448-.132.465.047.89.183 1.277.408.386.225.725.537 1.017.937.292.399.514.885.668 1.456.077.289.098.492.063.609-.035.117-.14.199-.315.246L144.01 7.87zm7.703-5.526c.117-.202.246-.396.388-.58a3.273 3.273 0 0 1 1.048-.894c.212-.115.452-.208.72-.28a2.943 2.943 0 0 1 1.21-.088c.375.057.71.188 1.005.394.295.205.55.476.764.813.215.338.381.728.5 1.17l1.352 5.047-1.908.511-1.352-5.046c-.13-.484-.341-.829-.634-1.035-.293-.206-.666-.248-1.119-.127-.33.089-.619.246-.867.473a3.44 3.44 0 0 0-.656.83l1.537 5.734-1.91.511-2.123-7.928 1.166-.313c.248-.066.441.006.58.217l.3.591zm-48.507 31.624l2.124 7.929-1.167.312c-.252.068-.443-.005-.572-.219l-.301-.598c-.236.416-.523.779-.86 1.087-.337.309-.77.534-1.302.676a2.914 2.914 0 0 1-1.206.087 2.38 2.38 0 0 1-1.005-.397 2.82 2.82 0 0 1-.77-.817 4.182 4.182 0 0 1-.5-1.17l-1.35-5.039 1.909-.511 1.35 5.038c.13.485.342.83.637 1.035.296.205.667.247 1.115.127.33-.088.62-.244.869-.468.249-.225.468-.5.656-.826l-1.536-5.734 1.909-.512zm3.931-.01c.117-.202.246-.395.387-.58a3.273 3.273 0 0 1 1.048-.894c.213-.114.453-.207.72-.28a2.943 2.943 0 0 1 1.211-.087c.374.057.709.188 1.004.393.295.205.55.477.765.814.214.337.381.727.5 1.17l1.352 5.046-1.909.512-1.352-5.046c-.13-.484-.34-.83-.634-1.035-.292-.206-.665-.249-1.118-.127-.33.088-.62.246-.868.472a3.44 3.44 0 0 0-.655.83l1.536 5.734-1.909.511-2.124-7.928 1.167-.312c.247-.067.44.006.58.217l.299.59zm11.922-2.581a.527.527 0 0 1-.116.217.435.435 0 0 1-.203.108.706.706 0 0 1-.318.003c-.12-.023-.257-.049-.413-.076a3.48 3.48 0 0 0-.522-.046 2.356 2.356 0 0 0-.65.091c-.377.101-.65.26-.821.477a.772.772 0 0 0-.153.712c.045.17.139.298.28.384.143.086.317.149.523.187.206.039.435.062.685.07.25.007.507.02.768.038.262.018.523.049.783.092.26.044.503.122.73.236.226.113.425.268.597.465.171.197.3.455.385.775.102.38.128.75.078 1.11a2.36 2.36 0 0 1-.383.996 2.962 2.962 0 0 1-.846.815 4.463 4.463 0 0 1-1.311.563 4.47 4.47 0 0 1-.82.14c-.273.021-.54.02-.804-.003a4.294 4.294 0 0 1-.747-.132 3.34 3.34 0 0 1-.64-.242l.245-.844a.645.645 0 0 1 .147-.255.583.583 0 0 1 .275-.148.639.639 0 0 1 .363.01c.124.039.265.078.425.118.16.04.343.068.549.085.206.017.453-.014.741-.091.227-.06.414-.14.562-.238.148-.097.263-.204.345-.32a.826.826 0 0 0 .15-.367.947.947 0 0 0-.023-.38.664.664 0 0 0-.288-.41 1.505 1.505 0 0 0-.523-.192 4.404 4.404 0 0 0-.69-.068 21.41 21.41 0 0 1-.78-.035 6.883 6.883 0 0 1-.795-.097 2.536 2.536 0 0 1-.74-.254 1.973 1.973 0 0 1-.607-.507c-.177-.218-.313-.502-.407-.852a2.364 2.364 0 0 1-.055-.98c.05-.328.17-.635.362-.92a2.92 2.92 0 0 1 .794-.776 4.032 4.032 0 0 1 1.242-.544 4.102 4.102 0 0 1 1.564-.13c.496.06.933.198 1.31.411l-.248.804zm7.467-.386a2.378 2.378 0 0 0-.292-.671 1.72 1.72 0 0 0-.467-.492 1.507 1.507 0 0 0-.634-.248 1.88 1.88 0 0 0-.784.056c-.551.148-.943.422-1.176.82-.233.4-.315.9-.248 1.5l3.6-.965zm-3.331 2.127c.14.399.306.73.499.997.192.266.407.47.644.614.238.143.497.228.777.255.28.027.575 0 .885-.083.309-.083.566-.19.77-.323.205-.132.38-.264.523-.397.144-.132.27-.251.377-.357a.765.765 0 0 1 .338-.207c.16-.043.294-.015.403.083l.735.548a3.293 3.293 0 0 1-.544.813 4.128 4.128 0 0 1-.716.622 4.657 4.657 0 0 1-.816.446c-.285.121-.567.219-.845.293a4.385 4.385 0 0 1-1.611.138 3.564 3.564 0 0 1-1.454-.48 3.941 3.941 0 0 1-1.183-1.108c-.342-.474-.607-1.059-.793-1.754a4.544 4.544 0 0 1-.146-1.597 3.8 3.8 0 0 1 .42-1.446c.232-.44.557-.827.973-1.16.416-.332.92-.577 1.513-.736.5-.134.982-.177 1.447-.131.465.047.891.182 1.277.407.386.225.725.538 1.017.937.292.4.515.885.668 1.457.077.288.098.491.064.608-.035.117-.14.2-.316.246l-4.906 1.315zm7.827-5.129c.12-.54.314-.99.582-1.352a1.944 1.944 0 0 1 1.096-.73c.366-.097.681-.096.946.004l.259 1.463c-.001.1-.02.175-.06.227a.32.32 0 0 1-.18.11c-.078.022-.196.04-.355.054a2.75 2.75 0 0 0-.455.08 1.656 1.656 0 0 0-.539.245 1.469 1.469 0 0 0-.373.385c-.1.152-.178.323-.235.515-.056.191-.1.405-.13.64l1.308 4.883-1.909.512-2.124-7.929 1.12-.3c.196-.052.342-.054.438-.005.096.048.18.16.255.333l.356.865zm9.521-.754a2.378 2.378 0 0 0-.292-.671 1.72 1.72 0 0 0-.467-.492 1.507 1.507 0 0 0-.634-.248 1.88 1.88 0 0 0-.784.057c-.55.147-.943.42-1.175.82-.233.399-.316.899-.249 1.5l3.601-.966zm-3.33 2.127c.139.399.305.73.498.997.193.266.408.47.645.614.237.143.496.228.777.255.28.027.575 0 .884-.083.31-.083.566-.19.77-.323.206-.132.38-.264.524-.397.144-.132.27-.251.376-.357a.765.765 0 0 1 .338-.207c.16-.043.294-.015.403.083l.735.548a3.293 3.293 0 0 1-.544.813 4.128 4.128 0 0 1-.715.622 4.657 4.657 0 0 1-.816.446c-.286.121-.567.219-.845.293a4.385 4.385 0 0 1-1.612.138 3.564 3.564 0 0 1-1.454-.48 3.941 3.941 0 0 1-1.182-1.108c-.343-.474-.607-1.059-.794-1.754a4.544 4.544 0 0 1-.146-1.597 3.8 3.8 0 0 1 .42-1.446c.233-.44.557-.827.973-1.16.417-.332.92-.577 1.513-.736.5-.134.982-.177 1.448-.131.465.047.89.182 1.277.407.386.225.725.538 1.017.937.292.4.514.885.667 1.457.078.288.099.491.064.608-.035.117-.14.2-.315.246l-4.907 1.315zM104.056 54.95l.487-.13c.196-.053.35-.124.465-.212a.853.853 0 0 0 .263-.348l2.038-4.729c.084-.199.189-.35.313-.452.125-.102.295-.183.511-.24l1.793-.481-2.519 5.653c-.145.342-.32.605-.526.787.187.016.363.061.53.135.165.074.335.185.506.332l5.281 4.192-1.831.491c-.247.066-.44.08-.58.044a.896.896 0 0 1-.387-.224l-4.267-3.28a.857.857 0 0 0-.418-.202c-.144-.022-.337 0-.58.064l-.656.176 1.317 4.915-2.08.557-2.993-11.174 2.079-.557 1.254 4.683zm14.66-5.469l2.125 7.929-1.167.312c-.252.068-.443-.005-.572-.22l-.301-.598c-.237.417-.523.78-.86 1.088-.337.308-.771.534-1.302.676a2.914 2.914 0 0 1-1.206.087 2.38 2.38 0 0 1-1.005-.397 2.82 2.82 0 0 1-.77-.817 4.182 4.182 0 0 1-.5-1.17l-1.35-5.039 1.909-.511 1.35 5.038c.13.484.342.83.637 1.034.295.206.667.248 1.115.128.33-.088.62-.244.869-.469.249-.224.468-.499.656-.826l-1.536-5.733 1.908-.512zm4.055.388c.12-.54.314-.991.582-1.353a1.944 1.944 0 0 1 1.096-.728c.366-.098.681-.097.946.003l.259 1.463c0 .1-.02.175-.06.227a.32.32 0 0 1-.18.11c-.078.021-.196.04-.355.054a2.75 2.75 0 0 0-.455.08 1.656 1.656 0 0 0-.539.245 1.469 1.469 0 0 0-.373.385c-.1.151-.178.323-.235.515-.056.191-.1.405-.13.64l1.308 4.883-1.909.511-2.124-7.928 1.12-.3c.196-.053.342-.054.438-.006.096.05.18.16.255.334l.356.865zm8.847-2.188a.527.527 0 0 1-.116.217.435.435 0 0 1-.203.108.706.706 0 0 1-.318.003c-.12-.024-.257-.049-.413-.076a3.48 3.48 0 0 0-.522-.046 2.356 2.356 0 0 0-.65.091c-.377.1-.65.26-.821.477a.772.772 0 0 0-.153.712c.045.17.139.298.28.384.143.086.317.149.523.187.206.039.435.062.685.07.25.007.507.02.768.038.262.018.523.049.783.092.26.044.503.122.73.235.226.114.425.269.596.466.172.197.3.455.386.774.102.382.128.752.078 1.11a2.36 2.36 0 0 1-.383.997 2.962 2.962 0 0 1-.846.815 4.463 4.463 0 0 1-1.311.562 4.47 4.47 0 0 1-.82.141c-.273.021-.54.02-.804-.004a4.294 4.294 0 0 1-.747-.13 3.34 3.34 0 0 1-.64-.243l.245-.845a.645.645 0 0 1 .147-.254.583.583 0 0 1 .275-.149.639.639 0 0 1 .363.01c.124.04.265.079.425.119.16.04.343.068.549.085.206.016.453-.014.741-.091.227-.061.414-.14.562-.238.148-.097.263-.204.345-.32a.826.826 0 0 0 .15-.367.947.947 0 0 0-.023-.38.664.664 0 0 0-.288-.41 1.505 1.505 0 0 0-.523-.192 4.404 4.404 0 0 0-.69-.068 21.41 21.41 0 0 1-.78-.035 6.883 6.883 0 0 1-.796-.097 2.536 2.536 0 0 1-.738-.254 1.973 1.973 0 0 1-.608-.508c-.177-.217-.313-.501-.407-.852a2.364 2.364 0 0 1-.055-.979c.05-.328.17-.635.362-.92a2.92 2.92 0 0 1 .794-.777 4.032 4.032 0 0 1 1.242-.544 4.102 4.102 0 0 1 1.564-.129c.496.06.933.197 1.31.411l-.248.804zm7.467-.386a2.378 2.378 0 0 0-.292-.671 1.72 1.72 0 0 0-.467-.492 1.507 1.507 0 0 0-.634-.249 1.88 1.88 0 0 0-.784.057c-.551.148-.943.421-1.176.82-.233.4-.315.9-.248 1.5l3.6-.965zm-3.331 2.127c.14.398.306.73.499.996.192.266.407.471.644.615.238.143.497.228.777.255.28.027.575 0 .885-.084.309-.082.566-.19.77-.322.205-.132.38-.265.523-.397.144-.132.27-.252.377-.358a.765.765 0 0 1 .338-.206c.16-.043.294-.015.403.082l.735.549a3.293 3.293 0 0 1-.544.812 4.128 4.128 0 0 1-.716.623 4.657 4.657 0 0 1-.816.446c-.285.12-.567.218-.845.293a4.385 4.385 0 0 1-1.611.138 3.564 3.564 0 0 1-1.454-.48 3.941 3.941 0 0 1-1.183-1.108c-.342-.474-.607-1.059-.793-1.755a4.544 4.544 0 0 1-.146-1.596 3.8 3.8 0 0 1 .42-1.446c.232-.44.557-.827.973-1.16.416-.332.92-.577 1.513-.736.5-.134.982-.178 1.447-.131.465.046.891.182 1.277.407.386.225.725.538 1.017.937.292.4.515.885.668 1.457.077.288.098.49.064.608-.035.117-.14.199-.316.246l-4.906 1.315zm14.86.01l-1.839.493a.52.52 0 0 1-.365-.019 1.057 1.057 0 0 1-.279-.19l-2.416-2.31c-.002.095-.01.186-.022.272-.013.086-.03.168-.054.246l-.869 2.693a1.275 1.275 0 0 1-.143.3.459.459 0 0 1-.28.194l-1.707.458 1.625-4.817-3.641-3.14 1.839-.494a.66.66 0 0 1 .324-.024c.078.02.154.067.229.141l2.37 2.198c.01-.19.043-.384.1-.582l.778-2.445c.062-.22.184-.355.364-.404l1.754-.47-1.598 4.454 3.83 3.446zm2.348-2.832c.286.205.572.327.856.367.284.04.575.02.874-.06.288-.078.534-.202.737-.372.203-.17.356-.388.458-.653.103-.265.153-.578.15-.939a4.96 4.96 0 0 0-.188-1.229 5.487 5.487 0 0 0-.428-1.148 2.357 2.357 0 0 0-.53-.699 1.312 1.312 0 0 0-.625-.305 1.634 1.634 0 0 0-.713.043c-.397.106-.712.28-.945.522a3.181 3.181 0 0 0-.599.918l.953 3.555zm-1.385-4.764c.227-.453.516-.848.867-1.185.352-.337.805-.58 1.362-.73a2.691 2.691 0 0 1 1.259-.047c.406.085.785.263 1.137.536s.666.642.942 1.106c.277.464.502 1.021.676 1.67.158.593.225 1.163.201 1.71a4.17 4.17 0 0 1-.332 1.497 3.27 3.27 0 0 1-.841 1.157 3.236 3.236 0 0 1-1.326.691c-.443.119-.84.152-1.191.1a2.873 2.873 0 0 1-.995-.343l.87 3.246-1.909.511-2.818-10.517 1.167-.312c.247-.067.44.006.58.217l.351.693zm12.606-1.266a2.378 2.378 0 0 0-.291-.671 1.72 1.72 0 0 0-.468-.492 1.507 1.507 0 0 0-.634-.249 1.88 1.88 0 0 0-.784.057c-.55.148-.943.421-1.175.82-.233.4-.316.9-.249 1.5l3.601-.965zm-3.33 2.127c.14.398.305.73.498.996s.408.47.645.614c.237.144.496.23.777.256.28.027.575 0 .884-.084.31-.083.566-.19.77-.322.206-.132.38-.265.524-.397.144-.133.27-.252.376-.358a.765.765 0 0 1 .338-.206c.16-.043.294-.016.403.082l.735.549a3.293 3.293 0 0 1-.544.812 4.128 4.128 0 0 1-.715.623 4.657 4.657 0 0 1-.816.446c-.286.12-.567.218-.845.293a4.385 4.385 0 0 1-1.612.137 3.564 3.564 0 0 1-1.453-.48 3.941 3.941 0 0 1-1.183-1.107c-.343-.474-.607-1.06-.794-1.755a4.544 4.544 0 0 1-.146-1.596 3.8 3.8 0 0 1 .42-1.446c.233-.44.557-.827.973-1.16.417-.332.92-.578 1.513-.736.5-.134.982-.178 1.448-.131.465.046.89.182 1.277.407.386.225.725.537 1.017.937.292.4.514.885.668 1.457.077.288.098.49.063.608-.035.117-.14.199-.315.246l-4.907 1.315zm7.826-5.13c.12-.54.315-.99.582-1.352a1.944 1.944 0 0 1 1.097-.728c.366-.098.68-.097.945.003l.26 1.463c-.001.1-.021.175-.06.227a.32.32 0 0 1-.181.11c-.078.021-.196.04-.354.054a2.75 2.75 0 0 0-.455.08 1.656 1.656 0 0 0-.54.244 1.469 1.469 0 0 0-.372.386c-.1.151-.179.323-.235.514-.056.192-.1.405-.131.64l1.308 4.884-1.908.511-2.125-7.928 1.12-.3c.197-.053.343-.055.438-.006.096.05.181.16.255.334l.356.865zm8.396 4.907c-.69.185-1.271.132-1.744-.158-.472-.29-.8-.778-.984-1.463l-1.187-4.428-.811.218a.385.385 0 0 1-.29-.03c-.09-.048-.153-.139-.189-.273l-.202-.757 1.219-.55-.178-2.272a.439.439 0 0 1 .082-.279.452.452 0 0 1 .256-.16l.989-.264.669 2.496 2.117-.568.364 1.36-2.117.568 1.151 4.296c.067.248.179.424.337.531a.648.648 0 0 0 .555.075.93.93 0 0 0 .286-.122c.072-.05.134-.098.184-.145.051-.047.096-.09.135-.131a.274.274 0 0 1 .128-.08.226.226 0 0 1 .15.005c.044.02.094.051.15.097l.82.774a2.991 2.991 0 0 1-.817.782 3.692 3.692 0 0 1-1.073.478zm6.875-7.2a2.378 2.378 0 0 0-.292-.672 1.72 1.72 0 0 0-.467-.492 1.507 1.507 0 0 0-.634-.248 1.88 1.88 0 0 0-.784.057c-.551.147-.943.42-1.176.82-.232.4-.315.899-.248 1.5l3.601-.966zM180.62 37.4c.14.399.306.731.499.997s.408.47.645.614c.237.143.496.229.776.256.28.027.576-.001.885-.084.309-.083.566-.19.77-.323.205-.132.38-.264.524-.397.144-.132.27-.251.376-.357a.765.765 0 0 1 .338-.207c.16-.042.294-.015.403.083l.735.548a3.293 3.293 0 0 1-.544.813 4.128 4.128 0 0 1-.715.622 4.657 4.657 0 0 1-.817.447c-.285.12-.566.218-.845.292a4.385 4.385 0 0 1-1.61.138 3.564 3.564 0 0 1-1.455-.48 3.941 3.941 0 0 1-1.183-1.108c-.342-.474-.606-1.059-.793-1.754a4.544 4.544 0 0 1-.146-1.597 3.8 3.8 0 0 1 .42-1.446c.233-.44.557-.827.973-1.16.416-.331.92-.577 1.513-.736.5-.134.982-.177 1.447-.13.466.046.891.182 1.277.407.386.225.725.537 1.017.936.292.4.515.885.668 1.457.078.289.099.491.064.608-.035.117-.14.2-.315.246l-4.907 1.315zm7.704-5.526c.117-.203.246-.396.387-.58a3.273 3.273 0 0 1 1.048-.894c.213-.115.453-.208.72-.28a2.943 2.943 0 0 1 1.211-.088c.374.057.709.188 1.004.393.295.206.55.477.765.814.214.337.381.728.5 1.17l1.352 5.047-1.909.511-1.352-5.046c-.13-.484-.34-.83-.633-1.035-.293-.206-.666-.248-1.12-.127-.33.088-.618.246-.867.473a3.44 3.44 0 0 0-.655.83l1.536 5.733-1.908.512-2.125-7.929 1.167-.312c.247-.067.44.006.58.217l.3.59z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I didn't find a programatic solution to the problem. However, I let our designer know about the problem, so she took a look and - as she put it - she **"just flattened it again in Illustrator"**.

So if anyone has an issue with an SVG with text in paths, only in Safari, I suppose that's what you should ask your designer to do.

Note: The new SVG worked as a `background-image`. I didn't check the `<img>` version.

Answer (score 0):

Did the SVG work for standalone?

The SVG you refer to has a fill set to white on the containing group. When I tried to open it in chrome or safari I couldn't see it but it was there, I validated by changing the group tag to [image: Logo]

Either way, text in SVG can be problematic if the font isn't available so flattening to paths can be a good solution

Comment: Yep, it worked under Chrome, FF and IE11. Only Safari said "blah".